# Nivo stream chart change axisBottom values

Tags: reactjs, charts, nivo-react

I am trying to use nivo stream chart in react application

```
  const data = [
    {
      cxp_differnce: 600,
      cxp_utilized: 1000,
    },
    {
      cxp_differnce: 7000,
      cxp_utilized: 3000,
    }
  ];
```

Above is my data object i am passing to **ResponsiveStream**

```
     <ResponsiveStream
                    data={data}
                    keys={['cxp_utilized', 'cxp_differnce']}
                    margin={{ top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50 }}
                    axisTop={null}
                    axisRight={null}
                    isInteractive={false}
                    curve="linear"
                    axisBottom={{
                      //some values
                    }}
                    axisLeft={{
                      //some values
                    }}
                    colors={['#CFF295', '#939393']}
                    legends={[]}
                  />
```

I am getting the x axis values as ***0 and 1***
.[image]

i want to change it to custom labels

Answer (score 0):

axisBottom can be modifies as

```
   axisBottom={{
     format: customFunction,    
   }}
```

And write a function outside to return custom values using index

```
  const customFunction= (index) => {
    //index will be as per data object passing
    //index starts with 0
  };
```

You can write your custom logic inside above function